# How to increase popup size in the R Leaflet library as per the count?

Tags: r, dataframe, leaflet, geospatial

This is the dataframe named 'sellers_state_name_df' ->
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gnZU.png)

What I want is to increase the popup size of the circles as per the 'Freq'. For e.g Acre (1) circle should be smaller in size than let's say Bahia (19).

Here's the code snippet, which I used -> [Code Snippet of Leaflet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saFrh.png)

And the map that is generated -> [Generated Map using Leaflet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr5mz.png). If there is any solution or any alternative library (R), please let me know. Thanks!

I am expecting getting the popup size with respect to the 'Freq'.

Comment: It would be better to put the data, code and map in the post itself rather than providing `imgur` links.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg